# invisible vertical margin in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have the DIV(example) with 3 child DIV containing INPUTs in each.

In IE6 child DIVs have some invisible vertical margin or padding.

My HTML:

```
<form>
<dl>
    <dt><label>XXX</label></dt>
    <dd><input type="text" value="" name="surname"></dd>

    <dt><label>XXX</label></dt>
    <dd><input type="text" value="" name="firstname"></dd>

    <dt><label>XXX</label></dt>
    <dd><input type="text" value="" name="lastname"></dd>

    <dt></dt><dd><input type="submit" value="XXX" name="submit"></dd>
</dl>
</form>
```

I try display:inline, zoom:1, overflow ...

P.S. IE Developer Toolbar shows that element has no indentation

How to make normal render for IE6? Help please!

Comment: please provide an example (including code) so we can see what you mean.

Comment: Is it just a 1px margin/padding?

Comment: I don't see any divs. Plus, a code snippet which we can copy'n'paste'n'run (or a link to a jsfiddle.net demo) would help a lot. There are way too much red herrings and vagueness in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the HTML or CSS that you have, I can only suggest the following...

```
div{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

...which should work, even in IE6

Please provide more detail/example code in your question

Comment: @vitaly: divs don't have margin or padding by default, so a reset wouldn't help (even on top of them not being particularly helpful in the first place).

Comment: you are kind of right, but the 1px problem is probably related to the form and some elements having a default borders, so those have to be reset too.